# What model to use to match persons

Tags: machine-learning-model, azure-ml

To gain experience with AI, I am working on building a simple app where students can create a profile. The student's bio is read by NLP and the student is given a number of tags that he is good at. So suppose the student has written a bio in which he says that he does a lot of web development and is good at time management, then the student will receive the tags “web development” and “time management”.

I want to make a Tinder version to match students who could possibly work together. So suppose 2 students are interested in web development, then this is a match. But a student who is only interested in web development and the other is only interested in English and Data Science, then this is not a match. A student with the tag web development and a student with the tag programming can be a match. So the idea is that the model continues to learn based on whether users swipe left or right. my idea is to use Azure ML, but I have no idea which model is best to use.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.